# Bariometric formula derivation

Tags: statistical-mechanics

I don't understand the following reasoning that I found in a set of lecture notes from a physics course, it's about Perrin's stimate on $N_{a}$ Avogadro's number via the bariometric formula

In order to stablish that formula, the reasoning begins with Boltzmann distribution

$$\frac{n(E)}{n(0)}=\exp\left(-\frac{E}{k_{B}T} \right) $$

For a single particle, under the action of the Earth's gravitational field

$$E=\frac{p^2}{2m}-mgz $$

In the equilibrium

$$E=-mgz$$

substitution upon Boltzmann's distribution

$$\frac{n(z)}{n(0)}=\exp\left(-\frac{-(mgz)}{k_{B}T} \right) \propto \exp(z) $$

completely wrong

In the lectures notes that problematic minus sign is omitted. Where is (are) the error(s)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The energy obviously grows with the height $z$ (assuming that positive means up and negative means down) so it is
$$ E = \frac{p^2}{2m} + mgz $$
This sign error spread everywhere.